# Sequential Stern-Gerlach experiment on a budget

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, home-experiment

The sequential Stern-Gerlach experiment is important for historical and theoretical reasons; it demonstrates in a conceptually simple manner the consequence of having non-commuting observables with respect to the outcome of successive measurements of said observables (I am thinking here specifically of the exposition in the first chapter of Sakurai's 'Modern Quantum Mechanics'). I am interested here in the quantum nature of the measurement.

I am not an experimentalist. Is there any way to perform this experiment (or one morally the same) on a limited budget (and preferably at home)?   Explicit details are welcome.

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/8.13/www/JLExperiments/JLExp18.pdf
Here's one method of doing it on a reasonable budget.

Comment: @StevenSagona If you feel like it you could write up a summary and post it as an answer? Also, if you feel this is not a terrible question, how about an upvote :D?

Comment: @StevenSagona Although looking at the pdf, it does not seem to be about the sequential SG experiment?

Comment: the problem is the vacuum system, which is not necessarily  cheap.

Comment: Isn't polarizing filters "morally the same" as SG? That would make a good budget alternative.

Comment: @md2perpe Indeed, Sakurai makes the analogy with classically polarised light explicitly in the first chapter of the book I referred to. However, since that analogy can be explained without recourse to quantum mechanics (it does not require the notion of representing observables with operators)  it is not sufficiently 'quantum' to have the same moral.

Comment: It’s exactly isomorphic to SG is power levels are low (single photons).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Sure. Could you provide an answer for someone (like me) who does not know much about experimental physics as to how I could produce and detect individual photons (or at least bucket them) at home, and use this fact to perform a sequential SG experiment that illustrates in a nice way e.g. incompatible observables?

Comment: @MartinC. The problem is with the "at home" part and what you mean by "budget".  Getting detectors isn't that bad but the problem here will be to find a room sufficiently dark for purpose, and you might need to cool your photo-detectors etc.  The issue with replicating the "original" one is the volume over which you need vacuum.  For inspiration (albeit not on a budget) see Porter, J., R. F. Pettifer, and D. R. Leadley. "Direct demonstration of the transverse Stern–Gerlach effect." American Journal of Physics 71.11 (2003): 1103-1108 ; see https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.1574321

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thanks for the updated info. By all means expand it as an answer if you like.

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186482/42966