# Paper with sequential Stern-Gerlach experiments

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-spin, resource-recommendations, history

Often sequential Stern-Gerlach experiments are taken to motivate basic quantum mechanics. But I can't find a paper where these are actually carried out experimentally. I have two questions:

1. Who was the first to link multiple Stern-Gerlach experiments?
2. Where can I find the paper on this?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186482/ has some suggestions for papers to look at.

Comment: "who was the first?" is not a physics question, but a history-of-physics one; as such, the [site consensus](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8930) indicates that it should be posted on [hsm.se].